# Pegar todos os ID dos eleitos em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom eu removo o CSS de um determinado elemento assim:

```
$('#menu' + this.id + '').removeClass('open');
```

O que eu preciso fazer e remover de todos os elementos `#menu` menos o do informado.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
!$('#menu' + this.id + '').removeClass('open');
```

Mas não deu certo.

Tenho varios `#menu` como `#menu1`,`#menu2`. Sendo que eles não se repetem no html. 
Preciso remover o CSS de todos, menos do `#menu` informado.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Podes mostrar mais do código/funcionalidade que queres fazer? Assim adaptamos as nossas respostas mais à tua realidade.

Comment: @Sergio ok, para ficar mais fácil eu postei todo o código. Bom clica com o botão direito na `<tr>` da tabela que  vai abrir um menu, preciso fazer ele fechar quando eu clicar na linha d'baixo.  https://jsfiddle.net/zj2sbpny/

Comment: Seria assim que queres? https://jsfiddle.net/d733a9ox/

Comment: +/-, como re retirou o`setTimeout` o efeito fica meu sugado, da uma olhada quando a tabela fica maior https://jsfiddle.net/d733a9ox/1/. Tem que ter o `setTimeout` para esperar o efeito terminar e depois remover a posição da div.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `not`:

```js
$('div[id^=menu').click(function() {
  // indica qual item não deve ser removido
  $('div[id^=menu').not($(this)).removeClass('open');
  visualizar();
});

// apenas visualizacao
function visualizar() {
  $('div[id^=menu').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('class'));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu1" class="open">1</div>
<div id="menu2" class="open">2</div>
<div id="menu3" class="open">3</div>
```

Comment: Do deu jeito ficou bom, mas não da para eu usar, pois eu passo o div que não pode ser alterado no `$(this)`. Preciso remover de todas, menos a que esta no `$(this)`.

Comment: Mudei a forma @HugoBorges, veja se é isso clicando em algum número para ver o resultado.

Comment: Esta dando esse erro no console. `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div[id^=menu`

Comment: Aqui no exemplo ou no seu projeto @HugoBorges?

Comment: No seu exemplo.

Comment: Estou testando no firefox e chrome e está executando normal :x

Comment: Verdade, o erro acontece no Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o `.toggleClass(classe, condição)` passando-lhe a verificação do ID para saber se deve adicionar ou remover a classe.

Exemplo:

```js
var idEspecial = 'menu1';
$('div[id^=menu').each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open', this.id === idEspecial);
});
```

```css
div {
  color: black;
}

.open {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu1" class="open">1</div>
<div id="menu2" class="open">2</div>
<div id="menu3" class="open">3</div>
```

Comment: Bom do seu jeito não vai funcionar comigo, pois faço vários coisas não é so remover a classe. Preciso de alguma forma de fazer isso em todas as div #menu, menos na que eu informei.

Comment: @HugoBorges é isso que o meu código faz. Remover todas e adicionar à que tem o dado ID. Se mostrares mais do que estás a fazer talvez haja outra maneira, mas para o código/problema que mostraste a minha resposta serve.